# Dynamic query select function based on a cell reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have several queries. Each week they need to shift one column right, C to D then E...W.

I currently manually change C to D in all my queries and I want to simplify.

A couple of examples:

```
select B,C,AM,AN,AP,AQ where C = 'Available' order by AM limit 20
```

and

```
select B,AM,AN where C = 'Available' order by AM limit 12
```

I've tried to make the query select dynamic and reference a cell "H2" with the new column select letter, so all the queries select change based on "H2" value C or D ... or W.

I've tried new value in "H2" is D,

```
select B,AM,AN where "H2" = 'Available' order by AM limit 12

select B,AM,AN where "&H2&" = 'Available' order by AM limit 12

select B,AM,AN where """&H2&""" = 'Available' order by AM limit 12
```

nothing works, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Your second version is correct. For example,

```
=query(B:G, "select B where " & H2 & " = 'Available'")
```

works correctly in my spreadsheet when H2 contains a letter such as C or D or E.

Answer (score 0):

```
select B,AM,AN where "&$A&" = 'Available' order by AM limit 12
```